# 山手線の電車遅延したらSlackに投稿するスクリプト

Tags: google-apps-script, slack

山手線が遅延していたらslackに投稿するスクリプトを作成しましたが、上手くslackに投稿できないです。実行すると次のようなエラーが表示されます。

**エラーメッセージ**

```
戻り値が無効です。（行 8、ファイル「Slack」）表示しない
```

下記のように出力して欲しいです。
お手数ですが、ご確認お願い致します。

**期待する出力結果**

```
平常運転
現在､事故･遅延に関する情報はありません。
```

**ソースコード**

```
// 日付取得、フォーマット整形
var currentDate = new Date();
var weekday = currentDate.getDay();
var date = Utilities.formatDate( currentDate, 'Asia/Tokyo', 'M月d日 HH時mm分');

// 祝日は実行させない
if (weekday == 0 || weekday == 6) {
  return;
}
var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('ja.japanese#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com');
if (calendar.getEventsForDay(currentDate, {max: 1}).length > 0) {
  return;
}

// URLから要素を指定し、タグ要素を取得する
var yahoo = "https://transit.yahoo.co.jp/traininfo/detail/21/0/";
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(yahoo);
var myRegexp_line = /<<dd class="normal"　trouble">([\s\S]*?)<\/div>/i;
var line_html = myRegexp_line.exec(response.getContentText());
var line_list = line_html[1];

// 文字の整形
// replaceでline_listをゴリゴリ整形し変数、lineに...(もっと綺麗に書きたかった。。) 
var line_base = line_list.replace(/\n|(運転状況|列車遅延|路線|詳細)|<td><span.*<\/td>|<.?th>|<tr>|<.?table>/g, "");
var line_top_del = line_base.replace("状況", "");
var line_td_del_1 = line_top_del.replace(/<td>/g, "\n");
var line_span_del = line_td_del_1.replace(/<\/span>|<\/a>/g, "");
var line_a_del = line_span_del.replace(/<a href=".*\/">/g,"");
var line_td_del_2 = line_a_del.replace(/<\/td>/g, "\n" );
var line = line_td_del_2.replace(/<\/tr>/g, "━─━─━─━─━─━─━─━");

if(line !== '事故・遅延情報はありません'){

  // slackに投稿
  function postMessage(message, hookPoint){
    var payload = {
      "text": message,
      "channelId": '#information',
      "userName": 'train-info',
      "icon_emoji": ':train:'
    }
    var options = {
      "method": "POST",
      "payload": JSON.stringify(payload),
      "headers": {
      "Content-type": "application/json",
      }
    }
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(hookPoint, options);

    if (response.getResponseCode() == 200) {
      return response;
    }
      return false;
  }
    postMessage("\n" + "◆関東遅延情報 " + date + "\n" + yahoo + "\n" + line,'メモしたWebhookURL');
}else{
    postMessage("\n" + "◆関東遅延情報 " + date + "\n" + "○　事故・遅延情報はありません。" + "\n"+ yahoo,'メモしたWebhookURL');
}
}catch(e){
  result = "エラーの内容:" + e;
    Logger.log(result);
    postMessage("◆Script実行エラーです。");
 }
}
```

Comment: Slack.gsというファイルを作成していますか？または、そのような名前のライブラリを利用していますか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

記載されたコードをGASのスクリプトエディタに貼り付けて保存すると、エラーメッセージが再現しました。
（ファイル名はSlack.gsですかね。）

> 実行すると次のようなエラーが表示されます。

こちらは「保存すると」という事でよろしいでしょうか？

上記であっているとして、回答いたします。
GASは関数を実行するので、関数化する事で対応が可能です。
具体的には以下のようにすればよいかと思います。

```
function hoge(){
  // 日付取得、フォーマット整形
  var currentDate = new Date();

  // 以下略
}
```

尚、記載されているコードは一部抜粋のようで、唐突にcatch句が出ているためそこで構文エラーとなります。
動作させるためにはその辺りの修正が必要ですが、本質問とはズレますので割愛いたします。

Answer (score 2):

コメント書けないのでこちらで確認したいんですが、8 行目は以下の処理ですね。

```
if (weekday == 0 || weekday == 6) {
  return;  ←←←←ここ
}
```

GAS は詳しくないんですが、何も返さない return は仕様として許容されているのでしょうか？